# Auto touch application for android

Tags: android

I want to create such type of application, App's record user key event. And recorded event play.
like this type of app [Auto Touch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.autotouch.autotouch&hl=en)

I am try to search on google for tutorial but not found.

Is there any way to create such type of application for **non rooted device**.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done .

Recording Events :
adb shell getevent command : You need to implement an algorithm to track events and convert hexadecimal values to decimal x,y coordinates

Play : use input tap